# I use a chrome extension that pops up a window and starts its data collection process when its icon is clicked

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, screen-scraping

As it is collecting data it makes visible a small rotating 'loaderImg' icon in the middle of its popup window.  When it has finished collected data the 'loaderImg' icon disappears.

Python allows me to open my OS default browser where the extension is already installed and a simple mouse click starts the process.

I'm am trying to use Python to monitor when the extension's rotating 'loaderImg' becomes visible, and when it disappears.

Selenium appears to be of no use because the browser instance that it execute is not my default OS browser.

Is it even possible to do with BeautifulSoup or not?

Can the elements from a chrome extension even be probed in the manner I've been trying?

....downloading and searching the source code while the extension's popup was visible doesn't contain any elements of the popup...